# need explanation about def function example

Tags: python-3.x

**Example Code for define function:**

What is "func" doing in this code and what is the purpose of def add, and how is the result 30.

```
def add(x, y):
  return x + y

def do_twice(func, x, y):
  return func(func(x, y), func(x, y))

a = 5
b = 10

print(do_twice(add, a, b))
```

**The actual result is "30".**

**provided statement:** "As you can see, the function do_twice takes a function as its argument and calls it in its body."

Answer (score 0):

Func is only the other name of the add function. It's actually a function variable. What it actually does is add(add(5,10),add(5,10)) ==> add(15,15) ==> 30